# Understanding「って意味で」

Tags: grammar

I can't wrap my head around the meaning of「って意味で」in the dialogue from a manga below. The speaker was explaining the reason why she wants a lover.

> 決まった人がいれば、いちいち惚れた腫れたやらなくて楽かなって...
>
> 傍で支える**って意味で**は、一番確かだろうしね

What is the role of「って」? Is it short for「という」? I don't understand what「意味で」means. What is the function of「で」here?

Does the second sentence mean something among the lines of "I think the meaning of supporting by side is the most certain"? I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this って is short for という. This で is a condition/scope marker, and this は is a contrast marker. ～という意味では is "in the sense of ～", "if you mean ～", or "in terms of ～". You have ignored the meaning of で in your translation.

> 笑えるって意味では面白い
> It is *omoshiroi* in the sense of laughable (but not in the sense of interesting).

> 傍で支えるって意味では、一番確かだろうしね
> As a means to support someone, it (having a steady) is the most certain (way).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wonder if で used as a condition/scope marker is an extended usage of で as a location marker? Also, can I interpret "as a means to support someone" as "in terms of supporting someone"?

Comment: @JimmyYang See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55564/5010) for similar examples. で has a lot of usages and I don't think it's good to think of this as an extension of something else. And yes, "in terms of supporting someone" should be fine.