# What is the meaning of 「って」 in this context?

Tags: grammar, manga, particle-って

I have scoured every article and every related answer in this forum that I can find, but even so I preemptively offer my apologies if this is covered elsewhere. I'm an intermediate Japanese learner, and came across this usage of って in a manga I'm reading (Death Note - 1):

> 死神がこんな事言うのもおかしいが生きてるって気がしなくてな...

The translation I came up with is "**It's funny that a god of death would say this, but I just didn't feel alive**", which seems correct given the context. However, I can't figure out what grammatical purpose the って is serving in 「生きてるって」. Can someone explain its usage here?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/84579/9831 「って is short for という」

Comment: 「『生きてる』って気がしない」 means 「『生きてる』という気がしない」. Does it not make sense?

Comment: Ah okay. Yes it does make sense. I just read the full answer from the linked question and having you write it out here, made it click for me